# while-loops and python

Tags: python, performance, while-loop, infinite-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why avoid while loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270167/why-avoid-while-loops)

I am trying to learn Python by following [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org) and as I have progressed along I found it mentioned on the site that,

> Use a while-loop only to loop forever, and that means probably never. This only applies to Python, other languages are different.

Now I am basically a Java developer and this got me wondering as to why `while` should be avoided in python although it is widely used in Java. I haven't been able to find any answer on the internet.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270167/why-avoid-while-loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That statement is highly subjective and I am not sure I'd agree with it. It is easy to have an infinite loop using `while` in Python:

```
  while True:
       # do stuff
```

Perhaps the author was comparing this with C where it is also easy to have an infinite loop with for:

```
  for(;;)
      /* do stuff */
```

No such corresponding construct really exists for Python.

Having said there there are plenty of instances where an infinite loop is useful (in any language) - think event loops, or where the loop control can be simplified by having an infinite loop and only certain conditions causing a `break`.

Frequently you'll be processing sequences such as list and strings and the use of a for-loop will be a natural fit, but I'd not dismiss the while-loop simply because of that.

Comment: but does while loop cause any sort of disadvantage to the code at all?

Comment: @AnuragRamdasan Not that I see .. though of course any ill-chosen language construct can. I.e., if your problem calls for a `for`-loop and you use a `while` it may not be the best choice, but it would still be workable. From a technical point of view I don't see a disadvantage.

Answer (score 3):

He says in [Exercise 33](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex33.html):

> Here's the problem with while-loops: Sometimes they do not stop.

It's not really a Python problem if you know what you are doing. ;)

Answer (score 1):

No freaking idea. As a matter of fact, `while` is the only "classical" way of looping in Python because `for` is the analoque of `foreach` in other languages (i.e. an operator that iterates over collections or iterators).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the `while` loop in Python, and it has its place when you are not dealing with an iterable.

But if you are dealing with an iterable (and this concept is very pervasive in Python), a `for` loop is always the better construct.

For example, in many languages you wold write something like:

```
while(! file.EOF) {
    ...
}
```

In Python you use:

```
for line in file:
    do_something_with(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn Python The Hard Way is fairly opinionated, so I wouldn't take this to mean you should never use `while`. My best guess is that because iterators are a pervasive pattern in Python, most actual iteration can make use of `for..in`. Java had the old `Iterator` pattern of using `while (it.hasNext()) { … }`, or something similar for reading JDBC `ResultSet`s, or from reading lines from standard input – all of which are doable with a `for..in` in Python. (Doable and arguably should be done; `for..in` is more readable, and `yield` makes it easy to write regular iterables, so there's little reason for a library not to expose an iterator API.)

Answer (score 1):

`for` is pretty much the "default" choice in Python when you want to iterate a definite number of times. For example:

```
for i in xrange(10):
    #do stuff
    #iterates 10 times

for an_element in a_collection:
    #do stuff
    #iterates over every element in a collection
    #though generators can be "infinite"
```

However, if you want to loop over code an *indefinite* number of times, a `while` loop is more idiomatic.

```
while a_boolean: 
    #do stuff
    #iterates as long as a_boolean evaluates to True

while True:
    #do stuff
    #iterates till a break is encountered
```

Since you come from a Java background, a `while` loop in Python is pretty much the same as a `while` loop in Java and is used in much the same way. A `for` loop in Python is like:

```
 for(Integer i : anArrayListOfIntegers){
     //do stuff
 }
```

The `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)` form doesn't exist in Python, you use the `range()/xrange()` form in the first example instead. That said, every `for` loop can be replaced with an equivalent `while` loop except in the case of list comprehensions/generator expressions and the like.

There are no real advantages or disadvantages to doing this in terms of speed or memory usage. However, Python programmers tend to use `for` when they are iterating over collections and `while` when they want to iterate *while* or *until* a condition is true. If you stick to this general rule of thumb, you probably won't go wrong.