# Divisible by 2: Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a function called `splitList(myList, option)` that takes a list and an option which is either `0` or `1` as parameters. If the value of the option is `0` the function returns a list consisting of the elements in `myList` that are negative and if the value of the option is `1` the function returns a list consisting of the elements in `myList` that are even (we consider 0 to be an even number, since it is evenly divisible by 2).

For example:

```
splitList([1,-3,5,7,-9,-11,0,2,-4], 0)
```

Would return the list:

```
[-3,-9,-11,-4]
```

Where as:

```
splitList([1,-3,5,7,-9,-11,0,2,-4], 1)
```

Would return the list:

```
[0,2,-4]
```

For this problem I must use a `for loop`.

Here is what I have:

```
def splitList(myList, option):
    negativeValues = []
    positiveValues = []
    evenValues = [] 
    for i in range(0,len(myList)):       
        if myList[i] < 0: 
            negativeValues.append(myList [i]) 
        else: 
            positiveValues.append(myList [i]) 

    for element in myList: 
        if option == 1: 
            myList [i] % 2 == 0 
            evenValues.append(myList [i]) 
            return evenValues 
        else: 
            return negativeValues
```

The only thing I cannot get it to do is to is sort the list and return all the numbers that are divisible by 2.

Comment: see the slice function. That´s all im saying.

Comment: @Tom: How would the `slice` function help? I mean, if you can say more.

Comment: @hughdbrown Nevermind, misread the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you where trying to achieve:

```
def splitList(myList,option):

    result = []

    if option == 0:
        for item in myList:
            if (item < 0):
                result.append(item)
    elif option == 1:
        for item in myList:
            if (item % 2 == 0):
                result.append(item)
    else:
        return "Option Error"

    return sorted(result)

print splitList([1,-3,5,7,-9,-11,0,2,-4], 0)
print splitList([1,-3,5,7,-9,-11,0,2,-4], 1)
print splitList([1,-3,5,7,-9,-11,0,2,-4], 2)
```

Outputs:

```
[-11, -9, -4, -3]
[-4, 0, 2]
Option Error
```

Comment: This worked for me. How would you convert this and use a "while loop"?

Comment: A `while loop` wouldn't be suitable here.

Comment: How would a write a while loop with the circumstances that are given?

Comment: `Goto previous comment` Read and **understand** [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920645/when-to-use-while-or-the-for-in-python/920692#920692)

Answer (score 4):

Using a loop is a bit redundant here since there's a standard function `filter` that does what you want: returns a new list with these elements of a list which match a given predicate.

Let's define the predicates first:

```
def is_even(x):
    return x % 2 == 0

def is_negative(x):
    return x < 0
```

Then you can easily define your function in terms of `filter`:

```
def splitList(myList, option):
    predicate = is_negative if option == 0 else is_even
    return filter(predicate, myList)
```

Comment: As an exercise, I suggest to write the `filter` function yourself.

Comment: you could also use `lambdas` to make it even shorter. I personally prefer an if wich has two return statements over an additional variable but that is a matter of taste. an requirement was that a `for` is used, otherwise I see the beauty in your code...

Comment: +1 I like your answer, but what do you make of this: "For this problem, you must use a “for loop”." Maybe: `return [x for x in myList if predicate(x)]`

Comment: You can implement `filter` yourself using a for loop, like I said in my first comment.

Comment: @hughdbrown using `map` and `filter` is very much like using list comprehensions; I use `map`/`filter` when I have the function ready and a comprehension when I'd have to write a lambda.

Comment: I'm familiar with `map`, `filter`, list comprehensions, and more. I was just saying that OP's question (from his prof? for homework?) has a requirement for a `for-loop`. Or, I agree: we wouldn't write it with a `for-loop` because we know better, but OP Is asking for it that way for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can build all your variants from these primitives:

```
def even_list(numbers):
    return [x for x in numbers if not (x & 1)]

def odd_list(numbers):
    return [x for x in numbers if x & 1]

def negative_list(numbers):
    return [x for x in numbers if x < 0]

def positive_list(numbers):
    return [x for x in numbers if x > 0]
```

Then test:

```
>>> def test():
...     numbers = list(range(-3, 4))
...     print even_list(numbers)
...     print odd_list(numbers)
...     print positive_list(numbers)
...     print negative_list(numbers)
... 
>>> test()
[-2, 0, 2]
[-3, -1, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[-3, -2, -1]
```

---

Later: so stealing from @Kos, you could write `split_list` like this:

```
def split_list(myList, option):
    predicate = negative_list if not option else even_list
    return predicate(myList)
```

Or:

```
def split_list(myList, option):
    predicates = [negative_list, even_list]
    return predicates[option](myList)
```

Not sure if it meets your needs if the `for-loop` is in a list comprehension in a called function.

[Also](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names): "Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability."

Comment: +1 for list comprehension

Comment: Didn't see this: 'For this problem, you must use a “for loop”.' Bah, humbug.

Comment: well true list comprehension is technically not a for loop one could argue, but I think it is good to see the option and I would count it as close enough, you basically have changed the order.

Comment: @Ted: "you basically have changed the order" Changed the order -- of what? The numbers are in the same order.

Comment: The syntactical order, instead of `loop, check condition, add to list` it reads `make a list from all elements looped over that match condition`

Answer (score 1):

You return too soon. You first have to complete the foor loop and return after it, not from inside the loop.

Example

```
for i in range(5):
    print i
    numbers.append(i)
    return numbers   //wrong: exit the function on the first pass in the loop.

for i in range(5):
    print i
    numbers.append(i)

return numbers       //right
```

Besides that why do you calculate the negative valuse list if you don't need it?

Answer (score 1):

```
def splitList(myList,option):

    negative_numbers = [i for i in myList if i < 0]
    even_numbers = [i for i in myList if i % 2 == 0]

    return sorted(even_numbers) if option else sorted(negative_numbers)
```

Comment: `odds = [i for i in myList if i % 2 == 0]` -- the code does not match the variable. `i % 2 == 0` will not find the odd numbers.

Comment: @hughdbrown you are right, wrong naming.