# Python: For loop using index instead of nested loop for 2 column output

Tags: python, indexing, nested-loops

I want my program to look like this, but when I run program I got an error. I don't know what I did wrong please help me. Thank you so much. Sorry my english is not good

Rainfall Statistics

```
Month           Total Rainfall
-----           ---------------
Jan                  10
Feb                  20
Mar                  15
Apr                  5
May                  4
Jun                  5
Jul                  3
Aug                  2
Sep                  8
Oct                  7
Nov                  10
Dec                  12

Total Rainfall:      96
Average Rainfall:    8.0
```

This is my code:

```
amount = []
total = 0

month = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
for num in range(1,13):
    am = int(raw_input("Enter amount of rainfall each month from Jan to Dec sequently: "))
    amount.append(am)
    total+=am

print "\nRainfall Statistics"
print "Month\t\tTotal Rainfall"
print "-----\t\t---------------"

for index in month:
    print month[index], "\t\t", amount[index]

print "\ntotal rainfall: ", total

average = total/12
print "\nAverage rainfall: ",average
```

This is my output:

```
Enter amount of rainfall each month from Jan to Dec sequently: 1
Enter amount of rainfall each month from Jan to Dec sequently: 2
Enter amount of rainfall each month from Jan to Dec sequently: 3
Enter amount of rainfall each month from Jan to Dec sequently: 4
Enter amount of rainfall each month from Jan to Dec sequently: 5
Enter amount of rainfall each month from Jan to Dec sequently: 6
Enter amount of rainfall each month from Jan to Dec sequently: 7
Enter amount of rainfall each month from Jan to Dec sequently: 8
Enter amount of rainfall each month from Jan to Dec sequently: 9
Enter amount of rainfall each month from Jan to Dec sequently: 10
Enter amount of rainfall each month from Jan to Dec sequently: 11
Enter amount of rainfall each month from Jan to Dec sequently: 12

Rainfall Statistics
Month       Total Rainfall
-----       ---------------
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matter_neverdie/Desktop/python/rainFall.py", line 15, in <module>
    print month[index], "\t\t", amount[index]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: `index` is a string not an integer

Comment: So, what line should I fix??

Comment: Thank you everybody for helping me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program should look some what similar to this

```
from itertools import izip

amount = []
total = 0

month = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
idx = 0
while(idx < len(month)):
    am = int(raw_input("Enter amount of rainfall each month from Jan to Dec sequently: "))
    amount.append(am)
    total+=am
    idx+=1

print "\nRainfall Statistics"
print "Month\t\tTotal Rainfall"
print "-----\t\t---------------"

for each_month, month_amount in izip(month, amount):
    print each_month, "\t\t", month_amount

print "\nTotal rainfall: ", total

average = total/12
print "\nAverage rainfall: ",average
```

When you iterate over the list using a for loop in Python you get the element and not a number like the C style for loops.

While iterating over multiple lists its always better to use tools present in the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module like the izip which has many advantages rather than iterate over one list and use an number index to iterate over the other.

You should also see when you need to use a for loop and while loop in Python. Although they might serve the same purpose in languages like C they can be used to accomplish different things in Python. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920645/when-to-use-while-or-the-for-in-python) might help you on when to use a for loop and when to use a while loop.

Answer (score 3):

Python, unlike some other languages like JavaScript, have `forin` loops iterate over the elements of the array and not the indices of the elements of the array. You meant to have

```
for index in range(len(month)):
```

Answer (score 0):

First, In your input-loop, it would be better style to write 
`for num in range(12)` which will loop 12 tiems and give you the indexes 0..11. This is favoured over your solution because you dont have to think about hov mny iterationy you really have.

You can use exact the same idea for the second loop:

```
for index in range(12):
```

would be working, but you can improve this by calculating the length of your list (maybe you want o have two years later on, etc) using `len()`. Threfore you should write

```
for index in range( len(month) ): #or len(amount)
```

In python, you can also get index and element of a list in a single line using the built-in [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).
With this, you could do the following:

```
for index, month in enumerate(month):
    print month, "\t\t", amount[index]
```

The last example is maybe not what you are aseked to do in your assignment ;o)...