# how to get the minimum increase in a table Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to get the minimum increase between rows in a column in my table.

my attempt so far

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 100, 50, 100],
                   'B': [5, 2, 2, 0],
                   'C': [10, 20, 40, 400]})

def lowestIncrease(data, value):
  table = data[value].pct_change().fillna(0)
  x = data[value][table == table.min(i for i in table if i > 0)].index[0]
  if x == 0:
    print( 0 )
  else:
    answer = data[value][x] - data[value][x-1]
    print( answer )
```

My idea to use `min()` the way that that I am came from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27966830/8705615

my desired output

```
in[1]:lowestIncrease(df, 'A')
out[1]:50
in[2]:lowestIncrease(df, 'B')
out[2]:0
in[3]:lowestIncrease(df, 'C')
out[3]:10
```

I feel like I'm close to what I'm trying to achieve, I just need to replace how I'm calling `table.min(i for i in table if i > 0)` to get my desired output. How do you get the lowest change in value above 0 in a table?

Comment: Should this be the minimum increase that is not negative?

Comment: yes the minimum increase that's not negative. if there are no positive increases it should return 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inputs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 100, 50, 100],
                   'B': [5, 2, 2, 0],
                   'C': [10, 20, 40, 400]})
```

Solution:

```
df.diff()[df.diff() >0].min().fillna(0)
```

**Output**

```
A    50.0
B     0.0
C    10.0
```

For a single column

```
d = df[['A']]
d.diff()[d.diff() >0].min().fillna(0)
```

**Output**

```
A    50.0
```

Comment: my code crashes if I leave `.fillna(0)` in but if I remove it it works. but 'B' return nan

Comment: If I run exactly as your post it works, but I'm trying to have the code for individual columns so i changed the `df`'s to `df[column_name]`. It crashes if I run it like this, but it doesn't look like it should.

Comment: I had to rap the entire second line for single column in a `float()` for anyone who wants the value only

Comment: or you can add *.values[0]*