# What is wrong with this approach for insertion sort?

Tags: python, sorting

Could anyone explain to me why the following method for insertion sort is wrong please?

```
def insertion_sort(m):
        n = 1
        while n < len(m)-1:
            current_value = m[n]
            if m[n] < m[n-1]:
                m[n] = m[n-1]
                m[n-1] = current_value
            n = n + 1
        return m

#how my code turned out:
m = [7,4,5] returned [4,7,5] instead of [4,5,7]
```

Answer (score 2):

See explanations in the code comments:

```
def insertion_sort(m):
    n = 1
    while n < len(m): # <-- end at the end of the list
        current_value = m[n]
        if m[n] < m[n-1]:
            m[n] = m[n-1]
            m[n-1] = current_value
        n = n + 1
    return m
```

Comment: Starting from `1` is fine... no?

Answer (score 0):

As alfasin mentioned, the problem is with the while loop condition!

You can actually use for loop for this scenario. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920645/when-to-use-while-or-the-for-in-python)

And to be more pythonic, you can swap two numbers as `a,b = b,a` as mentioned in the comments by @TigerhawkT3!

```
def insertion_sort(m):
    for n in range(len(m)): #iterate from 0 to m-1. auto increment value is by default 1
            if m[n] < m[n-1]: m[n], m[n-1] = m[n-1], m[n]
    return m
```

print insertion_sort([7,4,5])
            return m
    print insertion_sort([7,4,5])

Output:

```
[4, 5, 7]
```

Moreover, the one you've tried isnt actually the [insertion sort](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheInsertionSort.html) algorithm. You got to fine tune yours to for list with more than 3 elements!

Comment: If you're going to make it more Pythonic with `range`, you might as well also do a multiple assignment with `if m[n] < m[n-1]: m[n], m[n-1] = m[n-1], m[n]`, and then you don't need `current_value`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was about to do that! Anyways I've them in the edit. :)

Comment: And, of course, it could be good to note that this only makes one pass, so lists with more than three elements may not be fully sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation in the comments

```
def insertion_sort(array):
    # For each number in the list (not starting 
    # with the first element because the first
    # element has no prior (i.e., no array[j-1])
    for i in range(1, len(array)):
        # Set a temp variable j (totally not necessary
        # but is helpful for the sake of a visual)
        j = i
        # While j is greater than 0 (position 0 is the 
        # very beginning of the array) AND the current 
        # element array[j] is less than the prior element
        # array[j-1] 
        while j>0 and array[j] < array[j-1]:
            # Set the current element equal to the prior 
            # element, and set the prior element equal to
            # the current element (i.e., switch their positions)
            array[j], array[j-1] = array[j-1], array[j]
            # Decrement j (because we are moving each element
            # towards the beginning of the list until it is 
            # in a sorted position)
            j-=1
    return array

 array = [1, 5, 8, 3, 9, 2]
```

First for-loop iteration: `[1,5,8,3,9,2]` (`5` is already in a sorted position)
Second for-loop iteration: `[1,5,8,3,9,2]` (`8` is already in a sorted position)
Third: `[1,3,5,8,9,2]` (move `3` back until it's sorted)
Fourth: `[1,2,3,8,9]` (move `2` back until it's sorted)

Hope this slight illustration helps.