# Change stepsize of for loop while in loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

is there a method where I can change the stepsize of a for loop, while I am in the loop?

E.g. this doesn't seem to work:

```
stepsize = 1.
for i in np.arange(0.,10.,stepsize):
   print i
   if i > 5:
      print "change"
      stepsize = 0.5
```

Output:

```
0.0
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
change
7.0
change
8.0
change
9.0
change
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but you can using a while loop, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179757/changing-step-in-python-loop/46180145

Comment: No, since the range object is constructed before entering the `for` loop. The parameters on which it depends can then change, since these are already "copied" into the object.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem "copied" sounds misleading. Makes it sound like `np.arange` gives you some lightweight on-the-fly-computing object like `range` does, instead of a fully materialized array. I'd rather call it "used" than "copied".

Comment: Replace your simple `arange` with something more complex, like `np.r_[0:6:1,6:10:.5]`, which concatenates 2 `aranges`.  When working with `numpy` try not think iteratively.  Think in terms of arrays, and ranges of values.

Comment: Would you be willing to use a custom range object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem

The issue is that when you declare your for loop as such:

```
for i in np.arange(0.,10.,stepsize):
```

The range object gets evaluated *before* the loop starts executing, and then never gets modified. As an analogy, consider this integer example:

```
a = 0
b = a + 1 #b is evaluated using the *current* value of a, which is 0
a = 1
print(b) # 0 + 1 = 1
```

The same applies for this for loop declaration, as it is equivalent to:

```
myRange = np.arange(0.,10.,stepsize)
for i in myRange:
    #...
    stepsize = 0.5 #will NOT affect the already initialized myRange variable!!
```

---

### A simple solution

Therefore, **the easiest solution** is, in my opinion, to **simply use a while loop**, and increment your counter according to your if condition:

```
i = 1.
while i < 10:
    print i
    if i > 5:
        print "change"
        i += 0.5 #condition met, increment by 0.5 instead of 1
    else:
        i += 1 #otherwise, increment by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not with `np.arange`, as that gives you a fully materialized *array*:

```
>>> r = np.arange(0., 1000000., 1)
>>> type(r)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> r.__sizeof__()
8000048
```

So after it is created, it's simply too late. Also, it has no access to your `stepsize` variable, so couldn't notice that you changed it.

Compare to `range`, which is a lightway object that calculates values on the fly:

```
>>> r = range(0, 1000000, 1)
>>> type(r)
<class 'range'>
>>> r.__sizeof__()
24
```

(Note I'm using Python 3... you should really join us. Not just because in Python 2 the equivalent has the ugly name `xrange`.)

Now... that `range` object does have a `step` attribute:

```
>>> dir(r)
['__bool__', '__class__', ..., 'count', 'index', 'start', 'step', 'stop']
```

But it won't let us change it:

```
>>> r.step = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#46>", line 1, in <module>
    r.step = 2
AttributeError: readonly attribute
```

You could use your own range class supporting such a state change, though:

```
class Range:
    def __init__(self, start, stop, step):
        self.current = start
        self.stop = stop
        self.step = step
    def __iter__(self):
        while self.current < self.stop:
            yield self.current
            self.current += self.step

for i in (r := Range(0, 10, 1)):
   print(i)
   if i > 5:
      print("change")
      r.step = 0.5
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
change
6.5
change
7.0
change
7.5
change
8.0
change
8.5
change
9.0
change
9.5
change
```