# Why aren't iterations skipped in a for loop when the loop variable is incremented?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
def loop():
    for i in range (0,9):
        pass
        if i == 3:
            i = i +3

        print(i)

loop()
```

Current output :

```
0
1
2
6
4
5
6
7
8
```

Expecting output:

```
0
1
2
6
7
8
9
```

Does this have to do something with the way stack frames are created in Python? 
Why doesn't the number of iterations reduce even though we increment i ?

Comment: `i` isn't a magical variable that controls the loop. You might want to use `while` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of `i` does not have any bearing over the loop execution. That is determined by... `range(0, 9)` (or, `range(9)`). The `for` loop is meant to iterate over an iterator, and iterates for a set number of iterations. If you want to skip loop iterations, you'd do that with a condition controlled `continue`.

For your case, though, I'd suggest the `while` loop, the more idiomatic choice for this sort of requirement.

```
i = 0
while i < 9:
    ... # something happens here
    if i == 3:
        i += 3
    else:
        i += 1
```

Further reading; [When to use "while" or "for" in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920645/when-to-use-while-or-for-in-python)

Comment: another idiomatic way would be chaining two ranges.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Assuming this is the only condition controlling the loop, yes.

Comment: You could always chain more ranges. :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Phew! That's certainly the opposite of idiomatic.