# Trying to build a simple calculator in Python can't manage to iterate between math symbols

Tags: python, calculator

```
# take operand    
print('Select operator') 
operator = str(input('Choose between + or * or - or /'))
if operator in ("+", "*", "-", "/"):
pass
else:
print ('error')
operator = str(input('Choose between + or * or - or /'))
```

I am trying to make it check if the entered symbol is, in fact, one of these "+", "*", "-" or "/"

If they enter a letter, for example, I want it to return that they should only one of the symbols. It works with a lot of elifs but it also prints four times that the symbol is incorrect. I want to fix that.

Comment: you have indentation errors

Comment: Use `while` loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: It doesn't work. I am trying to show errors for letters, not just numbers. I need iteration script that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Georgy was correct and this is very similar to the answer they linked to above. However, you have a few other issues that you might be running into that might be confusing you. I think what you are looking for is something similar to this:

```
# take operand    
print('Select operator')
while True:
  operator = str(input('Choose between + or * or - or /'))
  if operator in ("+", "*", "-", "/"):
    break
  else:
    print('error')
    continue

print(operator)
```

You want to use `while True` because you want this to repeat until you reach an ending condition. You could also potentially set a variable and change the value within the while loop instead of doing `break` and `continue`. However, in this case, if you hit the ending condition (the user has typed in valid input), then you want to `break` out of the while loop. If not, you want to `continue`. I would also recommend this question and answer on stackoverflow: [When to use "while" or "for" in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920645/when-to-use-while-or-for-in-python)