# Difference between for and while

Tags: python, list, for-loop, data-structures, while-loop

When i try for loop to remove all a's from list here is my code:

```
list5 = ["a","b","a","b","a","b","c"]
def remove_values_from_list(_list, val):
        for val in _list:
            _list.remove(val)
remove_values_from_list(list5, "a")
print(list5)
```

it return's:

```
["b","b","b"]
```

and when i use while instead of for it returns:

```
list5 = ["a","b","a","b","a","b","c"]
def remove_values_from_list(_list, val):
        while val in _list:
            _list.remove(val)
remove_values_from_list(list5, "a")
print(list5)



["b","b","b","c"]
```

Can someone explain me why does for loop doesn't return last c?

Comment: Where is your `while loop`?

Comment: @user5173426 in the same code change while instead of for.

Comment: @BarotShalin Include that part too in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use "while" or "for" in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920645/when-to-use-while-or-for-in-python)

Comment: Why should your for loop return `["b","b","b"]` when it actually should return `['b', 'b', 'b', 'c']`

Comment: @user5173426 coz it's really bad idea to remove elements using for loop. As you remove elements list gets smaller.

Comment: Trimming a list while iterating through it is tricky.

Comment: For the first example, the `val` parameter you're passing to your function gets overwritten and the for-loop just loops over all elements - it only looks like it's almost doing what you want because it's skipping every second element (in short: removing elements using a for-loop is not a good idea). The while loop is basically repeatedly checking the entire list looking for the element ("while `a` is in the list, remove `a`"), which is slow. Related: [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your for loop first, it should be:

```
def remove_values_from_list(_list, val):
        for _val in _list:
            if _val == val:
                _list.remove(val)
        print(_list)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['b', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```

and then so would the while loop:

```
def remove_values_from_list(_list, val):
    while(val in _list):
        _list.remove(val)
    print(_list)

remove_values_from_list(list5, "a")
```

OUTPUT:

```
['b', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```

**EDIT:**

You should alter your while loop a bit like:

```
while True:
    if val not in _list:
        break
    else:
        _list.remove(val)
print(_list)
```

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks @Dukeling for the catch:

You cannot remove elements (consecutive ones) from a list while iterating over it using a `for-loop`. For it, we can iterate over a copy of it like:

```
def remove_values_from_list(_list, val):

    for _val in _list[:]:
        if _val == val:
            _list.remove(_val)
    print(_list)

list5 = ["a", "a"]

remove_values_from_list(list5, "a")
```

OUTPUT:

```
[]
```

Comment: Ohh got it! Thank you very much for help

Comment: I already tried, but I have to wait for few minutes as I have just post the question. Thanks for help.

Comment: @BarotShalin I edited the answer of a better use of while loop

Comment: yeah that's more efficient i guess! Thank you.

Comment: @BarotShalin You may accept the answer that helped!

Comment: Yup I did! Thanks

Comment: @Dukeling Ah, Good catch, updating!

Comment: @Dukeling Updated.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using `val` in for loop and the parameter your function receives is called `val` too.

Try something like this:

```
def remove_values_from_list(_list, val):
    for v in _list:
        if v == val:
            _list.remove(v)
```

More efficient way to do this is:

```
def remove_values_from_list(_list, val):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x!=val, _list ))
```

Comment: got it! Thanks for help