# quick sorting using 'for' vs 'while'

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

'''

```
def swap_elements(my_list, index1, index2):
    my_list[index1], my_list[index2] = my_list[index2], my_list[index1]

def partition(my_list, start, end):

    p = end
    b= start
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if my_list[i] < my_list[p]:
            swap_elements(my_list, i, b)
            b += 1
    swap_elements(my_list, b, p)
    p = b
    return p
            
def quicksort(my_list, start, end):
    if end - start < 1:
        return my_list
    else: 
        p = partition(my_list, start, end)
        partition(my_list, start, p-1)
        partition(my_list, p+1, end)
'''
```

When I use this code because of second function 'partition' there is a IndexError: list index out of range.
However When I change the 'partition' code like this
'''

```
def partition(my_list, start, end):
    i = start
    b = start
    p = end

    while i < p:
        if my_list[i] <= my_list[p]:
            swap_elements(my_list, i, b)
            b += 1
        i += 1

    swap_elements(my_list, b, p)
    p = b

    return p
```

'''
It works.
I don't know the differences between for and while. Does anyone knows the answer?

Comment: `len(my_list)` is not a valid index within `my_list`

Comment: Try using `len(my_list)-1`, instead of `len(my_list)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quicksort with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262306/quicksort-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the choice of the `for` vs. `while` loop, since they are functionally the same. It has everything to do with the bounds. You have written the following line for the `for` loop:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
```

whereas you have written the following lines for the `while` loop:

```
i = start
b = start
p = end

while i < p:
```

You can see that these lines are not the same. In the `for` loop, you are iterating over the length of the entire array, whereas in the `while` loop, you are iterating from the bounds you are given. Therefore, you should modify the range of the `for` loop like so:

```
p = end
b= start
for i in range(start, p):
```

Also, you should modify the `quicksort` method like so to ensure that it runs:

```
    p = partition(my_list, start, end)
    quicksort(my_list, start, p-1)
    quicksort(my_list, p+1, end)
    return my_list
```

Comment: Calling the for and while loop functionally the same is a bit of an oversimplification of [the differences between the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920645/when-to-use-while-or-for-in-python).

Comment: @MrR True, my point was that there is no difference in the actual internal behavior of a `for` vs `while` loop. The OP seemed to understand that they had to manually iterate in the case of the `while` loop, and the issue with the `for` loop was simply with the chosen bounds.