# Printing -1 to -10 in python exercise

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, range, sequence

```
# the answer key
for num in range(-10, 0, 1):
    print(num)
```

I wanted to see if I could find a way to do it without using range():

```
i = -1
while abs(i) <= 10:
    print(i)
```

I'm new to python.

Thank you.

Comment: Remove the `abs` and increment `i` after the print

Comment: If you are using a while loop, you need to define your update rule for `i`, otherwise it will stuck there.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/920652/16343464)

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?
It will mimic the range version you have in the question.  Printing from -10 to -1 in increments of 1

```
i = -10
while i < 0:
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

Comment: It just mimic the range, print anything between -10 and -1 with increments of 1